Sea voyage to an oracle on an island
At this point I’m not sure if what I’m thinking of is one story, or if I’ve blended multiple stories in my mind.
I think the book starts out with ships bigger than anyone has seen before arriving from who knows where, and they take the woman the protagonist is supposed to marry (arranged marriage) and he offers to go after her.
In order to find her, the protagonist journeys to an island to consult an oracle. They stop along the way at an island infested with creatures of some kind. Their ship is sunk, maybe by sea serpents. They make it to the oracle and the oracle gives them a boat so they can continue on. I think the villain also visits the oracle.
And maybe there was an emperor across the sea?
This could eiter be a book, e-book, audio book, or something I read online. I think this was one book in a series. I think probably I read it in the last 10 years or so, but I read a lot, so that doesn’t narrow it down much.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When would you have read this?  Do you have any idea where?  (Book, e-book, online...)

Unfortunately could be any of those, including audio book. I think this was one book in a series. I think probably I read it in the last 10 years or so, but I read a lot, so that doesn’t narrow it down much.

Are you thinking of C. S. Lewis' Voyage of the Dawn Treader? This is one of the Narnia series of books. In it:

There was a kidnapping in the Lone Islands.
Towards the end of their voyage, they visit an island with Ramandu, who serves as something akin to an oracle.
They stop at many islands, and one of them, the Magician's Island, could be characterized as 'infested' with (temporarily) invisible creatures making loud thumping noises.
Their ship, the Dawn Treader, is damaged and in need of repair after an encounter with a giant sea serpent.
A smaller number of the crew continue on past Ramandu's island, and eventually only a handful of the ship's compliment continues on in a rowboat or dinghy.
There are not really major villains in the story, except for internal villains (e.g., one of the characters is transformed spectacularly by his own greed at one point; this specific character is both antagonistic and unsympathetic at the start of the story, but goes through quite a bit of growth to overcome both those things throughout the book, and he's there at the end of the story too).
One of the characters leaves the rowboat in a tiny coracle, and vanishes into the land of the Emperor Across the Sea.

Here's some of the cover art of the book (there's several other editions/releases, but these are pretty typical for the covers):
  

Unfortunately no, I would definitely remember that one. It was my favorite book as a kid.

I’ve been trying to remember, and I think the book starts out with ships bigger than anyone has seen before arriving from who knows where, and they take the woman the protagonist is supposed to marry (arranged marriage) and he offers to go after her.
